# Insert with many Anto Number from Data Table to DataBase

Tags: sql, database, ado.net, datatable

I have 3 data tables to update database

- `Invoice` table, primary key is `InvoiceNo`
- `InvoiceProduct` table, primary key is `InvoiceProductNo` and foreign key `InvoiceNo`
- `InvoiceProductExp` table, primary key is `InvoiceProductExpNo` and foreign keys are `InvoiceNo` and `InvoiceProductNo`

Facts:

- One `InvoiceNo` has many `InvoiceProductNo`
- one `InvoiceProductNo` has many `InvoiceProductExpNo`

3 Data Tables data entry would be for example is

```
Invoice (InvoiceNo,...)
(0001,...)

InvoiceProduct (InvoiceProductNo, InvoiceNo)
(1,0001,...)
(2,0001,...)

InvoiceProductExp (InvoiceProductExpNo,InvoiceProductNo,InvoiceNo)
(1,1,0001,...) 
(2,1,0001,...)
(3,2,0001,...)
(4,2,0001,...)
```

The problem is I liked to use SQL Server generated `Identity` column for all primary keys of 3 tables

How can I prepare for `insert` statements?

```
Insert Into InvoiceProductExp values (auto_number, ?, ?)
```

How can I get `InvoiceProductNo` to insert into `InvoiceProductExp` table since `InvoiceProductNo` is auto number?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```sql
DECLARE @InvoiceNo INT
DECLARE @InvoiceProductNo INT

INSERT INTO Invoice ([Date])
VALUES (GETDATE())

SELECT @InvoiceNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO InvoiceProduct([InvoiceNo])
VALUES (@InvoiceNo)

SELECT @InvoiceProductNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO InvoiceProductExp ([InvoiceProductNo], [InvoiceNo])
VALUES (@InvoiceProductNo, @InvoiceNo)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa88e/1)** demo

Comment: thank you
does sql sever 2008 support SCOPE_IDENTITY ? it doesn't return anything but @@IDENTITY works but @@IDENTITY is not reliable

Comment: @deva You're welcome. Sure it does. The answer gives you a link to SQL Server 2008 documentation and sqlfiddle is also 2008. Now your problem with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is most certainly caused by fact that you are calling it out of scope where insert has been issued. ***SCOPE_IDENTITY() Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope.** A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.*

Comment: thanks that you reply, Scope_Identity() works

i have 3 tables and i am using dataAdapter
one InvoiceNo has many InvoiceProductNo
For InvoiceNo

Comment: thanks that you reply, Scope_Identity() works
but
i have 3 tables and i am using dataAdapter
one InvoiceNo has many InvoiceProductNo
For example InvoiceNo 001 can have InvoiceProductNo vlaue of both 1 and 2
how to solve this for insert statements?

Answer (score 0):

If your primary keys are of identity column type then you don't have to insert a value into the primary key column. The identity column will auto populate when the row is committed to the database.

Does this resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Why must manually? You can set your **ID** as automatically auto increment.
When you create table:

`UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`

**sample (create the table)**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tool(
   UserID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
)
```

**Inserting values**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Tool(Name) VALUES ('Person 1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Tool(Name) VALUES ('Person 2')
```